# Update Textfield in List Item in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile-listview

I want to use the input text style from jquery mobile. I have created a textfield dynamically from code behind and used inner html to dynamically add them in my listview. The listview's style was ok but then the style for textfield was the same as html's default style.

My javascript using ajax:

```
 $('#zaiko').live('click', 'li', function () {
    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "SP_F_080_I.aspx/clickEvents",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: '{"type": 2}',
        success: function (str) {
            hacyu.innerHTML = str.d;
            $('#hacyu').listview('refresh');

            $("#txtbnumOrders").trigger('create');
            $("#txtbremarks").trigger('create');
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `live()` has been deprecated and removed

Comment: ...and you should use `on` for newer jQuery versions (v1.7+) or `delegate` for older (v1.4.3+)

Comment: neither the two of you did answer my question. i really don't know how will i fix this problem...